# SQL Server Remote Connection on Centos 7 Increddibly slow

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, centos7, vps

I have an instance of SQL Server running on a Centos 7 VPS together with an application running on .net core 2.2.

I tried running the application on a separate VPS instance remotely connecting to the SQL Server VPS. But the queries where running really really slow. Like 100-500 times as slow to be precise.

I've also noticed that as of recently (it didn't use to) MSSMS also hangs for a bit each time I right click anything in the Object Explorer.

The connection string looks like the following:

```
Server=(IP of the VPS running SQL Server);Database=master;User Id=(username); Password=(password);
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: I didn't think Centos was officially supported for SQL Server?

Comment: CentOS and Redhat are almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was resolved by using servers geographically closer to each other.